# jquery fadein, delay issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

I have a piece of code here below that shows divs and stores it in a cookie and it hides them if the cookie exist. the problem is when i add my 3 seconds delay into one of the div id's when the page re-loads the the id with the delay keeps showing up

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
  //Search script to hide
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#popUpsearch').effect("pulsate", { times:2 }, 4000);
    $('#popUpsearch').fadeOut(5000); 

       $('#popUpsearch').load('a', function() {
         $.cookie('contentsearch','hid', { expires: 365});
     });

       if ( $.cookie('contentsearch') == 'hid'){
   $('#popUpsearch').hide();    
      };    
  $('#popUpnav').delay(3000).effect("pulsate", { times:2 }, 4000)
    $('#popUpnav').fadeOut(6000);
     $('#popUpnav').load('a', function() {
         $.cookie('contentnav','hide', { expires: 365});
     });
      if ( $.cookie('contentnav') == 'hide'){
     $('#popUpnav').hide();    
    };  
}); 

    //$(function() {
//   $.cookie('searchbox','sb3', { expires: 365});
//        if ($.cookie('searchbox') == 'sb3'){
//           $('#popUpsearch').hide();    
//        };    
//    }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your If block so your only performing one set of actions at a time.

```
if ( $.cookie('contentnav') == 'hide'){
  $('#popUpnav').hide();    
} else {
 $('#popUpnav').delay(3000).effect("pulsate", { times:2 }, 4000)
 $('#popUpnav').fadeOut(6000);
 $('#popUpnav').load('a', function() {
   $.cookie('contentnav','hide', { expires: 365});
 });
}
```